# Jboss jar deployment not persisting across server restarts

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

Using the jboss cli, We are deploying the Oracle Jdbc 12 (ojdbc7.jar) to a jboss server version 6.4, running with JDK 1.8.  The command looks like this:

```
call %JBOSSHOME%\bin\jboss-cli.bat  -c "deploy  %JBOSSHOME%\ojdbc7.jar --name=OracleJDBCDriver12c"
```

The command above succeeds, and jboss goes about its business with all Oracle datasources working as expected.  However, after we shutdown and restart the jboss server, the ojdbc deployment is "lost".  Here are some text from the server log, during startup:

```
09:13:54,716 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 12.1)
```

And then further down the log:

```
09:13:57,642 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014901: Content removed from location C:\java\jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\data\content\a2\348e4944956fac05235f7cd5d30bf872afb157\content
09:13:57,644 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015858: Undeployed "OracleJDBCDriver12c" (runtime-name: "OracleJDBCDriver12c")
```

It seems from the logs that jboss for some reason decides to undeploy the ojdbc jar deployment.  Would anyone have any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: are you placing the jar in the jboss's shared libs?

Comment: @AntJavaDev , no we are not placing the jar in the shared libs dir. I believe there is no need to place a jar deployed with the above method in  jboss's shared libs. Which is this directory anyway?

Comment: what you mean you are deploying the Oracle jdbc ? to deploy smth you need a web.xml

Comment: No, in jboss you can deploy jar files.  Please read up on jboss documentation.

Comment: maybe you should read the jboss documentation first  , because the deployment goes for a WEB APP not for a driver(jar). the driver is placed in the server's shared lib so that all the WEB APPs and the server's context would bind to that one

Comment: here is a link (for jboss 7 though) for how to configure the driver as a module(NOT deploying) https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7 and here is the link for JBOSS 6 in which as i told you already , you have to place the driver in server's shared libs directory http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Getting_Started_Guide/beta422/html/Using_MySQL_as_the_Default_DataSource-Installing_the_JDBC_Driver_and_Deploying_the_DataSource.html

Comment: OK, this question concerns a jar file deployed to jboss using the cli deploy command,  mentioned in my question above.  Not the method you mention in your above comment.

Comment: hmm , well still the logic doesnt change , have you checked this link https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes or https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Install_a_JDBC_Driver_as_a_Core_Module1.html , if you notice in both examples , they are not DEPLOYing but adding the driver